# how to add the data into the current session in python?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have one table **Org** in *server-1*

```
 class Org(db.Model, UserMixin):
       org_id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=True)
       org_name = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

I have another table **Employee** in *server-2*

```
class Employee(db.Model, UserMixin):
    emp_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    empname = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    org_id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=True)

   @staticmethod
   def org_name(org_id):
       organization_name = Emp_session.query(org).\
        filter(org.c.org_id == org_id).all()
    org_name = organization_name[0][1]
    return org_name


def checkEmp(email_username, password):
   user = Employee.query.filter_by(email=email).first() \
          or Employee.query.filter_by(empname =empname).first()
   if user.org_id or user.emp_id :
        name = user.org_name(user.org_id)
        print(name) #output: ABC Company
        return login_user(user, False)
else:
    return False
```

I have made a connection from *server-2* to *server-1* through **sqlalchemy**. I am getting the **org** *name* from *server-1*, I declared a `static` method inside the **Employee** table in *server-2*.

Here I want to add the name variable to the current *session* how can I do that?

Comment: when I print(current_user.org_name) I am getting output like this

" <function Employee.org_name at 0x000001D2850D60D0> "

how to make it in the proper format.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself, this might help others:

```
print(current_user.org_name(current_user.org_id))

output: ABC company
```